# Approved icons / 'media pack' for linking *to* stack exhange sites from external sites?

Tags: support, logo

I would imagine this has been asked before but perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms.

I'd like to link to [Korean Language Stack Exchange](https://korean.stackexchange.com/) from an external website - to make this link recognisable I'd like to use some recognisable stack exchange graphics. However, I think I remember in the past reading that SE wasn't always happy for its designs to be used by third parties.

Is there any approved 'site flair' or logo that I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [trademark guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> Do not use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Exchange Inc.

So you have to ask permission to use one of the SE logos. It seems they don't like you to use any logos without explicit permission.

I would use the *Contact Us* to ask the team permission. They can also tell you which logos you can use then.